# $3^{20} \pmod 5$ needing some guidance...

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$3^{20} \pmod 5$

So far I have:

By Fermat, $3^{5-1} \equiv 1\pmod 5$

$3^4 \equiv 1\pmod 5$

$(3^4)^5$

$(1)^5$

$\equiv1\pmod 5$

Does this look correct I getting a bit lost near the end and just wanted to confirm my answer. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's correct you can use the little Fermat's theorem$$ 3^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$$ therefore $$3^4\cdot 3^4\cdot 3^4\cdot 3^4\cdot 3^4 \equiv  1\pmod5$$